# v6: React-table multiple selection issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-table

I'm trying to apply a background color on selected rows:

```
getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column, instance) => ...}
```

on `rowInfo` I can't find any information like "selected" or similar (also using `selectTableHOC`)

Answer (score 1):

selected row column

```js
    getTrProps={(state, rowInfo, column) => {
        return {
          onClick: (e) => {
            var a = this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index);
            if (a == -1) {
              // this.setState({selected: array.concat(this.state.selected, [rowInfo.index])});
              this.setState({selected: [...this.state.selected, rowInfo.index]});
              // Pass props to the React component
            }
            var array = this.state.selected;
            if(a != -1){
              array.splice(a, 1);
              this.setState({selected: array});

            }
          },
          // #393740 - Lighter, selected row
          // #302f36 - Darker, not selected row
          style: {background: this.state.selected.indexOf(rowInfo.index) != -1 ? '#393740': '#302f36'},
        }
        }}
```

Comment: Ok, I have to handle an array with selected indexes, I was hoping there was a better solution..

Comment: you can check using this code too `getTrProps={(state, rowInfo) => {
const index = rowInfo ? rowInfo.index : -1;
return {
    onClick: () => {
        this.selectedRow = index;
        this.props.onRowclick(rowInfo.original._id);
    }
},
style: {
    background: this.selectedRow === index ? "gold" : null;
}    
}}`